# Выбор уникальных пар из базы данных

Tags: sql, mysql

Здравствуйте!

Есть таблица, состоящая из 3 колонок: `id (int)`, `A (int)` и `B(int)`. Она заполнена парами случайных значений *A* и *B* в диапазоне от 0 до *N* включительно, причем *A<sub>i</sub> ≠ B<sub>i</sub>*. Затем выбирается *x* из того же диапазона от 0 до *N* включительно.

Нужен запрос, извлекающий записи, для которых выполняются следующие условия:

1. Или *A*, или *B* равен *x*.
2. Пара `A, B` уникальна среди всех пар (К примеру, если имеется `(3, 1)`, то не может быть другой пары `(3, 1)` или `(1, 3)`).
3. Если в старой таблице есть несколько подходящих пар, то выбирается старшая по `id`.

---

### Примеры

Исходная таблица при `N = 5`:

```
id | A | B
---+---+---
 1 | 5 | 4
 2 | 0 | 4
 3 | 4 | 3
 4 | 3 | 5
 5 | 4 | 2
 6 | 1 | 2
 7 | 0 | 4
 8 | 0 | 5
 9 | 0 | 5
10 | 5 | 0
```

Выборка:

1. при `x = 0`:

   ```
   id | A | B
   ---+---+---
    7 | 0 | 4 - был еще вариант 2 | 0 | 4, но 7 > 2
   10 | 5 | 0 - был еще вариант 8 | 0 | 5 и 9 | 0 | 5, но 10 > 9 и 10 > 8
   ```
2. при `x = 1`:

   ```
   id | A | B
   ---+---+---
    6 | 1 | 2
   ```
3. при `x = 2`:

   ```
   id | A | B
   ---+---+---
    5 | 4 | 2
   ```

   6 | 1 | 2
4. при `x = 3`:

   ```
   id | A | B
   ---+---+---
    3 | 4 | 3
    4 | 3 | 5
   ```
5. при `x = 4`:

   ```
   id | A | B
   ---+---+---
    1 | 5 | 4
    3 | 4 | 3
    5 | 4 | 2
    7 | 0 | 4 - был еще вариант 2 | 0 | 4, но 7 > 2
   ```
6. при `x = 5`:

   ```
   id | A | B
   ---+---+---
    1 | 5 | 4 
    4 | 3 | 5
   10 | 5 | 0 - был еще вариант 8 | 0 | 5 и 9 | 0 | 5, но 10 > 9 и 10 > 8
   ```

Естественно это решаемо в рамках программного кода, так что вопрос состоит именно в запросе к MySql.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В t-sql

```
declare @x int = 0

select * from table

select * from table where id in (
    select  MAX(id) from table
    where a = @x or b = @x
    group by a + b)
```

Answer (score 1):

как-то так:

```
SET @prm = 0;

SELECT a.* 
FROM test a
JOIN (
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
        WHEN b.leftp IS NOT NULL AND a.id < b.id THEN b.id
        ELSE a.id END            
        as id 
FROM (SELECT leftp, rightp, max(id) as id
      from test  
      WHERE leftp = @prm OR rightp = @prm 
      GROUP BY leftp, rightp) a 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT leftp, rightp, max(id) as id   
       from test  
       WHERE leftp = @prm OR rightp = @prm 
       GROUP BY leftp, rightp) b 
ON a.leftp = b.rightp AND a.rightp = b.leftp
) b 
ON a.id = b.id
```